# Use While Loop twice with an else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I couldnt find something similar to my question.

I'm currently working on a Thread threader function.

I have two queues, one `r_queue` for regular and `p_queue` for priority.

```
def _threader(self):
    # Thread Handler
    while self.active:
        while self.p_queue.empty() and self.r_queue.qsize() > 0:
            # Regular Queue
            queue_dict = self.r_queue.get()
            self._complete_task(queue_dict, prioritized=False)

        (else?) while self.p_queue.qsize() > 0:
            # Prioritized Queue
            queue_dict = self.p_queue.get()
            self._complete_task(queue_dict, prioritized=True)
```

How can I use the (else?) properly here?

Edit: The idea behind the threader is, that it receives the data from the queue and completes the function. The first while is that it priorities the priority queue and only calls in case it has a size. (Cant get something when its None existent) My problem here is, that I need to add a while loop for the priority queue the line with `(else?) while self.p_queue.qsize() > 0:` but I cant just use straight else. If i would, it would constantly pick "Nothing" if the queue size is None existent. Something like `elif while self.p_queue.qsize() > 0` but that doesnt exist.

Comment: Can you describe in plain language how it should behave?

Comment: How is `self.p_queue.empty() and self.r_queue.qsize() > 0` supposed to work?

Comment: It's completely unclear what you expect that `else` to do or why you need it.

Comment: @jsmolka They're two different queues, so it works.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Whoops, overread the `p` and `r`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Updated

Comment: @Aran-Fey Updated

Comment: Why don't you just move the loop for the priority queue in front of the loop for the regular queue?

Comment: By the way, please read [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The whole `else` thing served no purpose but to make the question confusing. If your question is "How can I handle the priority queue before the regular queue?", don't ask "how do I make this `else` statement work?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the inner `while` loops as you can go with:

```
def _threader(self):
    # Thread Handler
    while self.active:
        if self.p_queue.qsize() > 0:
            # Prioritized Queue
            queue_dict = self.p_queue.get()
            self._complete_task(queue_dict, prioritized=True)
        elif self.r_queue.qsize() > 0:
            # Regular Queue
            queue_dict = self.r_queue.get()
            self._complete_task(queue_dict, prioritized=False)
```